# how to include a native library that use posix headers in android ndk

Tags: android-ndk, native, static-libraries, apk

I have to include a static native library (dsplink.a) which uses System V IPCs in android ndk project.

Including my library in android.mk as,

```
    LOCAL_LDLIBS := ($MY-PATH)/dsplink.a
```

gives the following error:

```
    _sync_usr.c:(.text+0x24b4): undefined reference to `semget'
    _sync_usr.c:(.text+0x24d4): undefined reference to `__errno_location'
    _sync_usr.c:(.text+0x24f4): undefined reference to `semget'
    _sync_usr.c:(.text+0x2538): undefined reference to `semctl'
```

semctl,semget,.. functions are included from sys/sem.h.
Is there any way to include the library ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly it isn't possible.

Extraction from android-ndk-r8/docs/system/libc/SYSV-IPC.html

Android does not support System V IPCs, i.e. the facilities provided by the
following standard Posix headers:

```
<sys/sem.h>   /* SysV semaphores */
<sys/shm.h>   /* SysV shared memory segments */
<sys/msg.h>   /* SysV message queues */
<sys/ipc.h>   /* General IPC definitions */
```

The reason for this is due to the fact that, by design, they lead to global
kernel resource leakage.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I can create a executable 'hello' using the same library and run it in the terminal as ./hello.It works perfect.Is there a way to create a apk file and run in the same way.

Comment: How do you create the executable (NDK?)
And in which terminal do you run it? (adb shell?)

Comment: I have created the executable using my board compatible toolchain.. And I run the executable in the serial port terminal connected to host ubuntu PC(in minicom)..

Comment: Okay, that's possible, but you can't use the library with Android NDK's bionic libc...

Comment: I have replaced the libc.so in the android NDK with the libc.so in my rootfs.But it results in the same error..

Comment: You can't use this in an >NDK< project as far as I know.
You have to find a workaround for deploying and executing your code, that you compiled with an external compiler.
See this as a start:

http://www.hytherion.com/beattidp/comput/android/linux-on-android.html

Comment: I have deployed and executed my code, compiled with external compiler and the Android Native Binary is running in serial terminal of my Android board...I need this to run as apk..

Comment: You can only bundle binary files with your apk in the assets folder or the res/raw folder.

Place your binary there and execute it, like shown here:

http://gimite.net/en/index.php?Run%20native%20executable%20in%20Android%20App